# Map as backing property for rich:pickList

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, seam

I want to use `Map<String, List<Object>>` as a backing property for rich:pickList as follows:

```
       <ui:repeat value="#{bean.selectedMap.entrySet" var="entry"} >
        <rich:pickList value="#{entry.value}" var="list" >
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.getAll}" />
            <f:converter converterId="myBeanConverter" />
         </rich:pickList>
       </ui:repeat>
```

backing bean:

```
public class MyBean {
private Map<String, List<String>> myList;
...
getters/setters for myList
}
```

the problem is I'm still getting this exception:

```
15:19:16,583 SEVERE [info.fingo.salutor.exception.CustomExceptionHandler] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-4) Critical Exception!: javax.faces.FacesException: ModelType (class java.lang.Object) must be either an Array, or a Collection
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:84) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]

Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: ModelType (class java.lang.Object) must be either an Array, or a Collection
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.SelectManyHelper.getConvertedValue(SelectManyHelper.java:332) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.SelectManyRendererBase.getConvertedValue(SelectManyRendererBase.java:108) [richfaces-components-ui-4.2.2.Final.jar:4.2.2.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.process(UIRepeat.java:532) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.processValidators(UIRepeat.java:766) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    ... 39 more
```

anyone knows what is it going about?

Answer (score 1):

If we close our eyes on the failure to close the EL expression properly (`}`), the problem is that there is indeed no `getEntrySet` method defined on a map instance. So, assuming that your environment supports EL 2.2, just put the function call, `()` at the end of your EL expression, to tell EL that it is a method call.

Next, [`<ui:repeat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) currently doesn't support iterating over a `Set`, so either create a helper getter that returns a `List`, or create a custom EL function, or use the `Set#toArray()` method.

For example, the latter will look like: `#{bean.selectedMap.entrySet().toArray()}`. For another alternatives, look at the answers on this topic to the questions that were already asked, and answered, on Stack Overflow.

Comment: In fact I have a factory method:
@Factory( value = "entrySetList", scope = ScopeType.EVENT, autoCreate = true )
 public List<Entry<String, String[]>> getEntrySetAsList(){...}
to return the list instead of set. Expression is not closed here by my mistake, when retyping the real code to the one in question. So both issues you mentioned are not the point. But, however, thank you for your consideration!

Comment: In case you have a `List` in fact, why do you ask for a `Map` solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. I have a list of map entries. Map is needed to model menu (key) and list of pages assigned to that menu.

Comment: Then you can use either of the three solutions proposed in the answer.